# How to share screen on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: remote-access

I am new to Ubuntu and am trying to share my screen (To a user who geographically sits thousands of miles away from me). 
Basically, he wants to control my desktop and perform some installation/up-gradation tasks.

I know in windows Team viewer can be used for this purpose but how to go about it on Ubuntu 11.04. Will the VNC viewer help? and if yes how to configure it so that i can share my screen and allow remote access through internet. Or are there some rpm packages available to do so ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just use teamviewer if you are know how to use it. http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx#downloadAreaLinux

You could use VNC but I find it a bit sluggish but this should help.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC

Comment: Also, encryption is not available for VNC on Linux.